# Within Eclipse, attach debugger to php file called from html file form tag

Tags: php, html, eclipse, wamp, xdebug

I have successfully setup Eclipse with PHP Development Tools with xdebug to debug stand alone PHP files. How do I attach the debugger to a PHP file that is called from a separate HTML file from within a form tag? Thanks.

I am using Eclipse Luna for PHP Developers, Xdebug, WAMP 2.4, PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

If you use a browser extension as mentioned at http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions then each PHP request will initiate a debugging request to an IDE (as long as everything is configured properly). As long as Eclipse listens to the incoming connection as well, you should be able to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, try to copy the .html file contents to a file with .php extension or just rename html to php. Then you'll be able to run and debug this php file from Eclipse.